# Why did my sheep die?

Tags: banished

I had 7 sheep in a pasture. I moved them to a larger one, and they all proceeded to die until none remained.

The pasture was worked, the slider was pushed all the way to right, and there was no infection (there used to be one a long time ago, but it was cleared for a long time).

What exactly happened?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a known bug in the game.

Comment: Can you elaborate some? Is it triggered by moving animals from herd to herd?

Comment: Yes, please provide a reference for this "known bug".

Comment: Not a dev or anything, when I posted the answer it was on the minecraft Wiki as known bug, but now its been fixed.

Comment: Answered a [tag:banished] question with info from a [tag:mincraft] wiki  and it gets upvoted and accepted....   Just Priceless.